# JHipster - Java build not compatible with the base image - jib

Tags: jhipster, jib

I run [a Docker image build command](https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#-docker-and-docker-compose) of a JHispter app

```
./mvnw package -Pprod verify jib:build
```

that yields an error:

```
Your project is using Java 17 but the base image is for Java 11, perhaps you should configure a Java 17-compatible base image using the '<from><image>' parameter, or set maven-compiler-plugin's '<target>' or '<release>' version to 11 or below in your build configuration
```

I find [a solution for Gradle](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/3704). How to do the same fix for Maven?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the image used using the property `<jib-maven-plugin.image>eclipse-temurin:17-jre-focal</jib-maven-plugin.image>` on the pom.xml, it should be defined as

```
<from>
  <image>${jib-maven-plugin.image}</image>
  <platforms>
    <platform>
      <architecture>${jib-maven-plugin.architecture}</architecture>
      <os>linux</os>
    </platform>
  </platforms>
</from>
```

In the jib-maven-plugin build definition, on the pom.xml as well.